# Conditional expectation of $\sin S_n$ given $S_n^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes

Consider the following exercise from Lawler's *Stochastic Calculus*:

> Suppose $X_1 , X_2 , \dots$ are independent random variables with
>   $$
> P\{X_j = 1\} = P\{X_j = −1\} = \frac12.
> $$
>   Let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$. Find
>   $$
> E(\sin S_n | S_n^2).
> $$

Let's start from a few simple cases:

1. $n=1$. Then certainly $S_n^2=1$, and 
   $$
   E(\sin S_1|S_1^2) = E(\sin S_1) = \frac12 \sin(1) + \frac12 \sin(-1) = \frac12\left(\sin(1) - \sin(1)\right)=0.
   $$
2. $n=2$. We may have $S_2^2=0$ or $S_2^2=4$. Both cases have probability 1/2. Then,
   $$
   E(\sin S_2|S_2^2=0) = 0
   $$
   because in this case $S_2=1 + (-1)=0$, and
   $$
   \begin{align}
   E(\sin S_2|S_2^2=4) &= \sin(2)\cdot P\{X_1=X_2=1|S_2^2=4\} + \sin(-2)\cdot P\{X_1=X_2=-1|S_2^2=4\} \\
   &=\sin(2)\left(\frac12 - \frac12\right) =0.
   \end{align}
   $$

Thus I am tempted to say that
$$
E(\sin S_n|S_n^2)=0,
$$
but I do not know how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: By symmetry the expectation is $0$. No need for any computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: By flipping the sign of $X_j$, all $j=1,2,\dots,n$, we have $\mathbb{P}(S_n=s\mid S_n^2=s^2)=\mathbb{P}(S_n=-s\mid S_n=s^2)$ for all $s$, so ...